# Retrieving Values from an Array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, preg-match-all

If you make an array and fill it with values with the function `preg_match_all` , how do you retrieve each separate value from the array (basically scan through it from index 0 to length)? I want to take each value and perform another function on it, so how would I return each value stored in the array? (I want arr's value at index 0, at index 1, etc.)

```
$contents = file_get_contents('words.txt');
$arr = array();
preg_match_all($pattern, $contents, $arr); //finds all matches
$curr = current($arr);
```

I tried doing this (my pattern was written elsewhere) and echoing it afterwards, but I keep getting the string "Array".

Comment: I would like to pick up, dust off, and answer this question.  Can you provide (as an edit to your question) a minimal, relevant sample of what `$contents` could contain? and can you explain exactly which parts you wish to capture?  With this new information, I can try to provide a solution for you.  Please ping me after you update the question.

Answer (score -1):

```
$contents=file_get_contents('words.txt');
$arr=array();
preg_match_all($pattern,$contents,$arr);//finds all matches
foreach ($arr as $item) {
  $curr=current($arr);
  // do something
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip on the foreach loop, but I am still getting that $curr is "Array" when echoed. Is it supposed to be returning "Array"?

Answer (score -1):

> `preg_match_all()` takes at least  Parameters: (1) The Regex. (2) The String to Match your Regex against. It also takes a third Optional Parameter which gets automatically populated with all the found matches. This 3rd Argument is a Numerically indexed Array. Thus you can loop through it like like you would a Normal Array as well as treat it like any normal Array (*which it is*). The Snippet below demonstrate this using your Code:

```
<?php

    $contents = file_get_contents('words.txt');
    //$arr    = array(); //<== NO NEED TO PRE-DECLARE THIS HERE

    preg_match_all($pattern, $contents, $arr);//finds all matches

    // IF YOU JUST WANT THE 1ST (CURRENT MATCH), SIMPLY USE current:
    $curr     = current($arr);
    // YOU MAY KEEP MOVING THE CURSOR TO THE NEXT ITEM LIKE SO:
    $next1    = next($arr);     
    $next2    = next($arr); 

    // OR JUST LOOP THROUGH THE FOUND MATCHES: $arr 
    foreach($arr as $match){
        $curr = current($arr); //<== BUT THIS IS SOMEWHAT REDUNDANT WITHIN THIS LOOP.

        // THE VARIABLE $match CONTAINS THE MATCHED STRING WITHIN THE CURRENT ITERATION:
        var_dump($match);      //<== RETURNS THE CURRENT VALUE WITHIN ITERATION
    }

    // YOU MAY EVEN USE NUMERIC INDEXES TO ACCESS THEM LIKE SO.
    $arrLen   = count($arr);
    $elem0    = isset($arr[0])?$arr[0]:null;
    $elem1    = isset($arr[1])?$arr[1]:null;
    $elem2    = isset($arr[2])?$arr[2]:null;
    $elem3    = isset($arr[3])?$arr[3]:null; //<== AND SO ON...
```

Answer (score -1):

If I understand well your question, you want to know how looks the results stored in the third parameter of `preg_match_all`.

`preg_match_all` stores the results in the third parameter as a 2-dimensional array.

Two structures are possible and can be explicitly set with two constants in the fourth parameter.

Let's say you have a pattern with two capture groups and your subject string contains 3 occurrences of your pattern:

1) `PREG_PATTERN_ORDER` is the default setting that returns something like that:

```
[
    0 => [ 0 => 'whole match 1',
           1 => 'whole match 2',
           2 => 'whole match 3' ],

    1 => [ 0 => 'capture group 1 from match 1',  
           1 => 'capture group 1 from match 2',
           2 => 'capture group 1 from match 3' ],

    2 => [ 0 => 'capture group 2 from match 1',  
           1 => 'capture group 2 from match 2',
           2 => 'capture group 2 from match 3' ]
]
```

2) `PREG_SET_ORDER` that returns something like that:

```
[
    0 => [ 0 => 'whole match 1',
           1 => 'capture group 1 from match 1',
           2 => 'capture group 2 from match 1' ],

    1 => [ 0 => 'whole match 2',
           1 => 'capture group 1 from match 2',
           2 => 'capture group 2 from match 2' ],

    2 => [ 0 => 'whole match 3',
           1 => 'capture group 1 from match 3',
           2 => 'capture group 2 from match 3' ]
]
```

Concrete examples can be found in the [PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php). You only need to choose which is the more convenient option for what you need to do.

So, to apply your function, all you need to do is to perform a `foreach` loop or to use `array_map` (that is a hidden loop too, but shorter and slower).

In general, if you aren't sure what is the structure of a variable, you can use `print_r` or `var_dump` to know how it looks like.